# trace with functools.partial

Tags: python, python-2.7, trace, functools

I am working on a project that uses the [`trace`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html) module to trace the execution of code.
When I call `trace.Trace(args).run(stuff)`, `stuff` has to be either a code object or a string.

For now, I am building the function that I will be calling with calls to `functools.partial`. This part works exactly as I need it to.

However, when I get to the tracing part, I am not able to execute the trace with a `functools.partial` object. I can't use `myFuncToolsPartialObject.func.func_name(args)` because I can't guarantee that the function will be imported into the local scope. I can get around this with a call to import, but would rather not, at the moment (let's call it a personal preference).

Is there a way by which I can turn the `functools.partial` object into a code object for a proper call to trace?

I know I can ask for `myFuncToolsPartialObject.func.func_code`, but I'm wouldn't know how to call it on the required arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that `trace` has built-in support for just this use case. `trace.Trace().runfunc(funcObject, *args)` does exactly this.

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html#trace.Trace.runfunc):

```
runfunc(func, *args, **kwds)
Call func with the given arguments under control of the Trace object with the current tracing parameters.
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
trace.Trace().run((lambda :partial_stuff(args)).func_code)
```

Comment: I get `TypeError: code object passed to exec may not contain free variables`. But otherwise, I wish I'd thought of this solution